# Reg Free COM and Click Once Winform

Tags: com, clickonce

I've read many of the questions on here and none of them seem to fit the bill so here goes:

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party COM dll into our clickonce deployed application:

I had to generate an interop assembly using the TLB the 3rd party provided (using tlbimp). This assembly along with the COM dll works perfectly when the COM dll is registered. When unregistered you get exceptions as expected. I then used the reg-free method described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) to generate a manifest file. This solved the issue on my local machine.

Now comes the problem. Clickonce deployment fails with "the xxx.manifest file already exists. I used brendan_maclean's [method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/ee94b07c-28de-4728-8e1e-37fd66e5f3d5) of making duplicates to get around the issues re: the dlls. But I can't get it to work for the manifest files.

Does anyone have any ideas? I do not want to have to resign the manifest after changing it to remove the extra link to the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the tutorial I followed doesn't work with Reg-free COM, because you are manually creating the manifest entry in the application's manifest.
What really needs to happen is that the sxs manifest you create has to be referenced by the project in the same way you would reference any other assembly (i.e. project->references).

This way the build process adds the link to manifest itself.